# How to remove milk smell from hardwood floor?

Tags: smell, hardwood

I spilled a bowl of cereal on my hardwood floor.  Now the whole room smells like sour milk.  Tried mopping with H2Orange and water a couple hours ago, but it still smells.  There are a couple of forum posts online that recommend vinegar, peroxide (H2O2), and scrubbing with hot soapy water but there didn't seem to be any feedback to say what worked and what didn't.

Has anyone had this problem before and know the right way to get rid of the smell?

UPDATE: So far I've tried mopping with H2Orange, mopping with Pinesol, scrubbing with baking soda and wiping up afterward with cleaner, and scrubbing with vinegar and water. The vinegar was the worst, because then it just smelled like spoiled milk with vinegar in it. I'm currently trying Old English oil, it's similar to Murphy's Oil Soap. Any other suggestions are kindly welcomed, I'm about to give up hope.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the thing that finally worked was Old English Oil! Murphy's Oil Soap will also work. Any other similar product/brand should do the trick too.